# Would it be possible to translate java to jruby?

Tags: java, jruby, translation, wrapper

Since jruby knows how to translate a ruby set of instruction into java ones, then is it also possible that jruby knows which ruby construct corresponds to a given java instructions?

Is it possible for jruby to make a reverse translation from java instructions to ruby ones ?

Has something similar already been implemented so far?

Thanks

Comment: Since JRuby/Ruby is a higher level language I would expect the Java version to be quite verbose. Have you tried compiling JRuby into bytecode and decompiling back to Java?

Comment: A naive translation would be relatively easy, but you'd end up with a slower version of the Java code, and it would be quite non-idiomatic. In JRuby you wouldn't need to do the translation (you'd jus use the Java classes), in another Ruby I'm not convinced it would be helpful.

Comment: @Tomasz I think you got me wrong here. In my question I am interested in the other way around, from java back to ruby. Yea, it's not questionable a java version would be more verbose. But even if they where "same level" ruby would be shorter ;)

Comment: @Dave for now I'm not interested in speed, and I guess I'll be able to adjust the resulting jruby code a little bit once I have a "draft" to operate on

Comment: I'm curious about what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

Just like you don't need to know how to make a cake in order to eat a cake, JRuby does not need to know how to convert java **code** into ruby code, so I don't think you will find this feature.

Of course, JRuby does know (thankfully) how to convert some Java types (particularly primitives, but also Array and hashes) into their ruby equivalents, but this is not what you asked.